# How does IdentityServer tracks which clients the user has signed into?

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect

With Identity Server 4, I am trying to notify clients that a user has signed-out via the front-channel specification for server-side clients (e.g. MVC). [this documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/signout.html) says;

> IdentityServer tracks which clients the user has signed into, and provides an API called GetLogoutContextAsync on the IIdentityServerInteractionService.

I am wondering how does IdentityServer tracks which clients the user has signed into ?
Is it stored in memory ? If yes, how does that work in a multi server + load balancer environment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default it stores that info as a property in the authentication cookie. You can provide your own mechanism by implementing `IdentityServer4.Services.IUserSession`. You can find the default implementation here:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/3.1.3/src/IdentityServer4/src/Services/Default/DefaultUserSession.cs

In our implementation we store user session data in a DB so the session client list is stored there too. This has the nice side effect of not being vulnerable to the race condition that can afflict the cookie method. Concurrent signin requests for different clients (which can happen in our solution) can cause one to be overwritten by the other.

Comment: Thank you @mackie, how do you override the DefaultUserSession ? I cannot find any doc mentionning the DefaultUserSession or the IUserSession.
I can find IdentityServerBuilderExtensionsAdditional.AddUserSession in the IdentiyServer Github repo but for an unknwon reason the method in unknown from my Startup class.

Comment: If the builder extension method is missing you can simply register the replacement service using the normal IServiceCollection methods: `services.AddScoped<IUserSession, CustomUserSession>();`. Make sure you do this after you register `identityserver4`.